# Transforming data to create generalized, quasi-proportional Venn diagrams using Package ‘nVennR’

Tags: r, algorithm, venn-diagram

I have the below dataset and would like your help to transform it in order to be able to plot a Venn Diagram using the [Package ‘nVennR’](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nVennR/index.html) by [Pérez-Silva et al. 2018](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/advance-article-abstract/doi/10.1093/bioinformatics/bty109/4904268?redirectedFrom=fulltext).

Here's the dataset:

```
dput(data)
structure(list(Employee = c("A001", "A002", "A003", "A004", "A005", 
"A006", "A007", "A008", "A009", "A010", "A011", "A012", "A013", 
"A014", "A015", "A016", "A017", "A018"), SAS = c("Y", "N", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", 
"N", "N"), Python = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y"), R = c("Y", 
"Y", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "N", "N")), .Names = c("Employee", "SAS", "Python", 
"R"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

See below an example of the Venn diagram I would like to get:

[image]

### Update:

After installing the updated version of `nVennR` and `rsvg`, when I run the example code from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nVennR/vignettes/nVennR.html) I get the error and diagram below:

```
Warning message:
In checkValidSVG(doc, warn = warn) :
This picture was not generated by the 'grConvert' package, errors may result
```

[image]

Below is my session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] nVennR_0.2.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.16       lattice_0.20-35    XML_3.98-1.10     
 [4] png_0.1-7          rsvg_1.1           grid_3.4.2        
 [7] plyr_1.8.4         gtable_0.2.0       scales_0.5.0.9000 
[10] ggplot2_2.2.1.9000 pillar_1.2.1       rlang_0.2.0.9001  
[13] grImport2_0.1-2    lazyeval_0.2.1     Matrix_1.2-12     
[16] tools_3.4.2        munsell_0.4.3      jpeg_0.1-8        
[19] compiler_3.4.2     base64enc_0.1-3    colorspace_1.3-2  
[22] tibble_1.4.2
```

I would appreciate any ideas to address this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick note to let you know that the new version of nVennR is ready. Input and output control is different now, and `toVenn` is deprecated, to be replaced by `plotVenn`. There is a vignette with several examples, one of which uses the data in this question, [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nVennR/vignettes/nVennR.html).

Comment: Hi, @vqf. Thanks for your great effort updating this excellent package. Just one issue: when I run the sample code from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nVennR/vignettes/nVennR.html) I get this warning: `Warning message: In checkValidSVG(doc, warn = warn) : This picture was not generated by the 'grConvert' package, errors may result`, and `'grConvert' package` is not available for windows currently according to [its author](https://sjp.co.nz/projects/grconvert/). In addition, the Venn diagram does not display well. Could you please address this issue?

Comment: Yes, nVennR uses `rsvg` instead of `grConvert`,  but I had never seen any warnings. Could you please try to update `rsvg` in your environment? Let me know if that fixes the issue. If that solves it, in future versions I will have to make sure I provide the minimal version of each dependency.

Comment: From the picture you show, the diagram is correct. The only problem is that the plot box gives a poor picture quality. However, the underlying picture is vectorial, and the resolution can be changed. If you export the result to a pdf, you will find a better version of the figure. If you export it to a bitmap (i. e., png), make sure you set the width and height to get a good resolution (for instance, 3200x1989). I am making a note to research how to manipulate the resolution of the plot window.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using the `limma` package in `Bioconductor` with your data loaded in from the `dput` as the variable `z`:

```
source("http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("limma")
library(limma)
```

Change all Y to TRUE and all N to FALSE:

```
z2 <- data.frame(lapply(z, function(x) { gsub("Y", "TRUE", x) }))
z3 <- data.frame(lapply(z2, function(x) { gsub("N", "FALSE", x) }),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Make sure they are all logical type:

```
z3$SAS <- as.logical(z3$SAS)
z3$Python <- as.logical(z3$Python)
z3$R <- as.logical(z3$R)
```

Now tally up all the totals for each Venn region using `vennCounts`:

```
> ( venn.totals <- vennCounts(z3[,-1]) )
  SAS Python R Counts
1   0      0 0      1
2   0      0 1      4
3   0      1 0      2
4   0      1 1      1
5   1      0 0      2
6   1      0 1      3
7   1      1 0      1
8   1      1 1      4
attr(,"class")
[1] "VennCounts"
```

Producing the diagram is just one more step:

```
vennDiagram(venn.totals)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @mysteRious. But I would appreciate your help to transform each variable of the original dataset into a `list` whose elements are equal to the values of the variable `Employee` when the value of these variables in the original dataset is equal to `TRUE` or `Y`. The idea is to transform the dataset into `sets of lists` that can be handled by `nVennR` or `VennDiagram`.

Comment: I tried using `nVennR` and it's extremely picky.. it won't accept a list of lists which is probably the issue you're running into. If you look into the code for `toVenn`, it makes the list of lists *for* you which is probably the main problem. Would strongly recommend not using a fancy colored Venn diagram though... the output from `nVennR` is really difficult to interpret.

Answer (score 1):

Nice to have feedback so fast. Perhaps we should have stated in the docummentation that this version of nVennR is preliminary. Some researchers had asked for a quick way to run nVenn, so I just wraped the C++ code into a couple of R functions. As you can see, the result is shown in the `viewer` window, instead of the `plot` window. I am learning as I go.
Since I see some interest on this package, I am compiling a list of features to add to the next version. Better input options are definitely in that list. Also, more control on the output (by the way, if colors are in the way, you can just set `opacity` to 0).

Regarding the question, @mysteRious is right, you send lists to the function. A quick way to do it would be

```
sas <- subset(data, SAS == "Y")$Employee
python <- subset(data, Python == "Y")$Employee
rr <- subset(data, R == "Y")$Employee
mySVG <- toVenn(sas, python, rr)
showSVG(mySVG = mySVG, opacity = 0.1)
```

The next version will have a method to enter names separately (sorry about that)

Comment: Thanks for the package, @vqf. Its ability to provide a visually attractive Venn diagram while being able to illustrate details makes it a valuable tool for my research. Adding more functions to allow more flexibility would, of course, be very helpful. In particular, your code here addressed my problem, but could you please give more tips on how to change the labels `name1`, `name2`, `name3`, and also `1`,`2`, and `3`, in the legend and plot, respectively?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding labels, the short answer is that you can edit them yourself with an SVG editor, such as Inkscape. If you have it installed, you can open the figure in the editor by running `showSVG(mySVG = mySVG, opacity = 0.1, systemShow=T)`. You can also save the figure by providing an output file (`outFile`) or just open the temporary file that is generated.

The somewhat longer answer is that name1, name2,... can be replaced with the names of the lists. Unfortunately, due to my limitations in R, I did not realise that this might not be straightforward. It would be easier to load each variable as a table and set the colNames. For instance,

```
sas <- as.table(subset(data, SAS == "Y")$Employee)
names(sas) <- 'SAS'
```

That label will be used at the legend. Regarding the small labels, currently there is no way for a user to change them. Those are meant to help read the location of specific regions, and when those regions are small it does not seem feasible to use longer labels. My advice would be to always use an external editor to change them. The future version will have at least the ability to remove those labels, like in the Web version.